# How to specify the reply-to address using sp_send_dbmail in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I need to send an email to someone and want them to be able to simply reply to the email without having to specify the email address.

Using sp_send_dbmail sets the reply-to address as the name of the profile that it was sent from.

Can this be changed to specify the reply-to so it looks like it came from me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Update: apparently the "@reply_to" parameter was added in SQL Server 2008.

SQL Server 2005 has no "reply to" parameter in `sp_send_dbmail`: 
 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

But SQL Server 2008 (2008 R2, 2012, etc.) does have a "reply to" parameter (@reply_to = 'yourReplyToEmailAddress'), in `sp_send_dbmail`: 
 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

> [ @reply_to= ] 'reply_to' 
>  
>            Is the value of the 'reply to address' of the email message. It accepts only one email address as a valid value. This is an optional parameter used to override the settings in the mail profile. This parameter is of type varchar(MAX). SMTP security settings determine if these overrides are accepted. If no parameter is specified, the default is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Not in sp send dbmail itself

The reply address is just text and can be set up in the profile.

Eg I configure bob@bob.com but the email account is private@isp.com

Hit reply and it goes to bob@bob.com

So, configure your profile used by the sp thus to show this.

[The line saying "The e-mail address to show on outgoing e-mail messages." here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190658.aspx)

[sp send dbmail help. no parameter for reply address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)

Comment: The `@reply_to` parameter was added in SQL Server 2008.  Links provided below.